# How a prototype property works in memory?

Tags: javascript

If prototype is shared between all instances, how a prototype property works?

```
function Foo() { 

}

Foo.prototype.property = 1;

var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();

a.property = 50;

console.log(b.property) // why this line shows 1?
```

If it's not shared, what's the difference between a prototype property and a constructor property in memory?

```
function Foo() { 

}

Foo.prototype.property = 1;
```

vs

```
function Foo() {
     this.property = 1;
}
```

Additional doubts:

- How this two different ways works in memory?
- Which one uses more memory and why?
- When I create a method in prototype it makes sense to me that it is shared between all instances, I think I'll have only one method loaded in memory, but I can't understand how a property works.

Comment: Think of prototypal inheritance (loosely) as a linked list. The `a` and `b` are distince objects, both of which have an implicit link to the `Foo.prototype` object, which has an implicit link to the `Object.prototype` object, which is the end of the list. So if `a` or `b` doesn't have a property named `property`, it looks to `Foo.prototype` to find it, and so on...

Comment: Assignments go directly on the object, not on its `[[Prototype]]` even if it has a same–named property. It's nothing to do with memory management and everything to do with how the assignment operator is specified to work.

Comment: The difference is in assigning `property` and mutating `property`. Try to make property an array and in instance a add an item to that array, you'll see the array also changes in instance b. Assigning a property to an instance is called shadowing, this and a lot more is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Foo() { 

}

// Hey, everybody, if anyone asks you about 'property'
// unless you have your own, use this one.
Foo.prototype.property = 1;

var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();

// Hey, you! You're special. You get your own property.
// This one covers the shared one.
a.property = 50;

// Hey you, B! You're using the shared one.
console.log(b.property) // why this line shows 1?
```

That is kind of the basic difference between 'prototype' and a local property.

If, on an object, you ask for a property that object doesn't have, it runs to its parent and ask "Hey!  Can I use yours?"  This goes all they  back to the root object.

For real fun, and a sure fire way to get your co-workers to hate you, set:

```
Object.prototype.something = true;
```

I'll be available everywhere and break all sorts of stuff.

---

```
// Everyone share this copy of property
function Foo() { 

}

Foo.prototype.property = 1;


// Hey everybody! You get your OWN copy of property! Ain't you special.
function Foo() {
     this.property = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a prototype and a constructor can be shown by modifying them after you create an object:

```
var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();

Foo.prototype.property = 50;
console.log(b.property); // This will show 50
```

If you put the assignment in the constructor, changing it will not affect objects that were already created.

In memory, the prototype is an object that's shared by all objects built from it. So instead of each object having its own copy of `property`, they all refer to a single prototype object; this uses less memory. If you refer to a property in an object, it first checks to see if it has its own property by that name. If not, it goes through the prototype chain, looking for the property.

There's no difference between methods and other properties in this regard. A method is just a property whose value happens to be a function. It's just that it's more common to share methods between all instances of a class than to share values. But a prototype property is a useful way to give every instance a default value for that property.

Answer (score 1):

> If prototype is shared between all instances, how a prototype property works?

An object's `[[Prototype]]` is only accessed when resolving property names to **get** property values. When assigning to a property, only the object itself is checked.

```
> function Foo() {}
> 
> Foo.prototype.property = 1;
> 
> var a = new Foo(); var b = new Foo();
> 
> a.property = 50;
> 
> console.log(b.property) // why this line shows 1?
```

That line shows `1` because when doing the assignment:

```
a.property = 50;
```

the object *a* is checked for a property named *property* and, since it doesn't have one, it's added and initialised with a value of `50`. Then when you do:

```
console.log(b.property) // why this line shows 1?
```

The object *b* doesn't have a *property* property so it's `[[Prototype]]` is checked and the property is found there with a value of `1`, so that is returned.

> If it's not shared, what's the difference between a prototype property and a constructor property in memory?

Your term "constructor property" should really be "instance property". Properties on the prototype are only accessed when *getting* a value, then are never accessed when *setting* a value.

> How this two different ways works in memory?

They are separate things, in one case you have created a property on the constructor's *prototype* and in the other a property on the object itself. How it "works in memory" is up to the browser author and really of no concern.

> Which one uses more memory and why?

That's irrelevant really. Even if there was a difference, it would be tiny and insignificant in the scheme of things.

> When I create a method in prototype it makes sense to me that it is shared between all instances, I think I'll have only one method loaded in memory, but I can't understand how a property works.

"Methods" are just properties too. You access them by reading the value, the same as reading the value of any property on an Object or its `[[Prototype]]` chain. But when you assign to an Object property, it is placed directly on the object itself, the `[[Prototype]]` chain is not considered.